# What does the minus sign mean in measurements in datasheet footprint drawings?

Tags: datasheet, footprint, drawing

I have seen this more than once where there is a measurement such as "4-0.7". In this context, it clearly does not mean 4 to 0.7 mm so what does it mean. See the attached picture:
[image: example of the above]

Link to datasheet: https://www.ckswitches.com/media/2780/pts526.pdf

Comment: Not confident enough to make this a proper answer but my guess would be that it's just like the ±, just without the +; it's specified to be no larger than 4 mm, and no smaller than 3.3 mm.

Comment: @Hearth Nah, it just means 4 pads at 0.7 mm. The long dimension is 1 mm, so it cannot be anything else.

Comment: How do you know it's a minus sign and not a hyphen, em dash or en dash?

Comment: @user110971 Now I feel dumb! Yeah, that's pretty obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks to me that it means four 0.7 mm wide pads.

Another way of writing it would be 0.7 (4 places)

Comment: Yes. It has to be that, because the tolerances are given either by: \$ 0,8 \pm 0,1 \$ or \$ 0,05^{0}_{-0,05}\$. Note the comma instead of the period :-)

Comment: If you look at page 3, top-left,  there's a measurement that reads "4-0,45±0,05". I just wanted to mention that as it furthers your statement.

Comment: It's too ambiguous to be a standard notation... isn't it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is European notation, so I’m not entirely sure. Usually you would use the hole symbol with the perpendicular lines in the middle. In documents with proper typesetting, the minus is actually longer than the hyphen. You can see this in the plus minus sign.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The drawing shows the pads as 1 mm long and 3.7 mm apart vertically, so they can't be 4 mm wide, if the drawing is anywhere near drawn to scale.

Comment: @PeterBennett Engineering drawings should not rely on the reader's visual estimation skills.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yes, that would be true in an Ideal World.  Unfortunately, we live in the Real World, where things are not always as we would like.